# How do I extract the lat and long from the following code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager, clgeocoder

How do I extract the lat and long from the follwoing code:

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [CLGeocoder new];
[geocoder geocodeAddressString:city completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

if ([placemarks count] > 0) {

    CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks lastObject]; 
    NSLog(@"Location is: %@", placemark.location);
```

}

from the nslog output I get:

```
Location is: <+45.46368100,+9.18817140> +/- 100.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 25/09/2013 11:04:20 British Summer Time
```

I would like to just get the lat and lon and store them into variables.

Comment: [CLPlacemark Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html). Tip: You are four clicks away from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = placemark.location.coordinate
```

then:

```
coordinate.longitude
coordinate.latitude
```

docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLPlacemark_class/Reference/Reference.html